# Merging Separate Clothing Onto a Rigged Character

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging

I've got a character that I've rigged and made clothes for. When I place to the clothes over him, they don't move.

So I followed a guide on how to fix that using "Transfer Weights", however this appeared to be an old guide as the same options are not available in my version (2.77).

So I followed a different guide on how to use "Data Transfer" in order to transfer the vertices groups and their inherent data onto my clothing.

This appears to work at first, however if my character moves his body parts too far away from the original pose, funny things happen with the clothing:

[image]

I've had a look at the weighting and that does seem to be identical to the main body, I'm not sure what's going on at all and I hope someone can point me in the right direction to welding this clothing onto my character.

The clothing is pretty much skin tight.

Thank you :)

Here is the base character without the extras doing the same pose:

Edit: The .blend file:

[image]

Had to remove second picture.

Comment: try to shrink wrap (modifier that you can remove after that) the cloth to the body before the data transfer

Comment: I just tried this but the same problem still occurs. Though the shrinkwrap does make it look nicer before the weirdness happens.

Comment: upload your file on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I uploaded my original broken character (before the shrink wrapping), less I add more confusion :)

Comment: Set it to *projected face interpolated* to have a better result. After that you will need to *generate data layer* and *apply* (data transfer is often simpler because of that). The result is not perfect though.